# Typescript Question：Functiong Type in Typescript Exercise 14

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am learning typescript in [typescript exercise](https://typescript-exercises.github.io/#exercise=14&file=%2Findex.ts)

in this subject solution，there is a function：

```
function toFunctional<T extends Function>(func: T): Function {
  const fullArgCount = func.length;
  function createSubFunction(curriedArgs: unknown[]) {
    return function(this: unknown) {
      const newCurriedArguments = curriedArgs.concat(Array.from(arguments));
      if (newCurriedArguments.length > fullArgCount) {
        throw new Error('Too many arguments');
      }
      if (newCurriedArguments.length === fullArgCount) {
        return func.apply(this, newCurriedArguments);
      }
        return createSubFunction(newCurriedArguments);
      };
   }
   return createSubFunction([]);
}
```

I dont understand this line：

```
const fullArgCount = func.length;
```

cause in that after，parameter `func` is a function，but whats the value of `func.length` ？

and whats `newCurriedArguments` actually mean ?

Comment: [`Function.prototype.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length)

Comment: very useful，thank for ur comment！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> and whats newCurriedArguments actually mean ?

```js
const newCurriedArguments = curriedArgs.concat(Array.from(arguments));
```

`newCurriedArguments` is the result of [concatenating](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) two arrays:

1. `curriedArgs` from `createSubFunction()` function, as the inner function where `newCurriedArguments` is declared has access to its parent function variables, and `curriedArgs` is one of them.
2. [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) which is the *arguments* of the function itself.

So you could say `newCurriedArguments` is the arguments of both the function and its parent.